# Orchard, to use customerPart or CustomerPartRecord

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Looking through orchard examples and I was wondering when is the correct time to use (for exmaple im using customer so...)

CustomerPart or CustomerPartRecord. when referring to them in Orchard projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you want to use the part. The record is used for storing the data in the part to the database. View templates and Drivers will refer to the part and the handler will say how the record is persisted.

If you follow the example through for [Creating a Simple Orchard Module](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor) and do as they do, it should become clearer. In particular check the 'Creating the Model for the Part' section.